# How to create zip stream from dynamic data (not by creating file at server or in memory)?

Tags: node.js, express, csv, stream, zip

I have some data that should be written to some CSV files and zipped, then stream the zip file to the client.

For this purpose, at the server side, for each file (each set of data that should be written in a csv file), I've created a transform stream and piped zip stream. I used native NodeJS [zlib](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) module:

```js
public async testCsvZip(@Res() res: Response) {
    const limit = 2;
    const object = (id: number) => {
        return { id, field1: 'test1', field2: 'test2' };
    };

    // Tell the browser that this is a zip file.
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Content-disposition': 'attachment; myFile.zip',
    });

    const zip = zlib.createGzip();
    zip.pipe(res);

    const writeDataToStream = (stream: Writable, chunk: any[]) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const done = stream.write(parseArrayToCsv(chunk), 'utf8', (e) => {
                if (e) {
                    console.error(e);
                    reject(e);
                }
            });
            if (done) {
                console.log('done');

                resolve(true);
            } else {
                stream.once('drain', () => {
                    console.log('drained');
                    resolve(true);
                });
            }
        });
    };

    const rows = 100;
    const writeToZipStream = async (csv: { name: string }) => {
        const stream = new Stream.Transform();
        stream._transform = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
            this.push(chunk);
            done();
        };
        stream.pipe(zip);

        stream.write(getHeader(object(0)), 'utf8');

        for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            console.log({ i });
            const chunk: any[] = [];
            for (let j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                chunk.push(object(i * rows + j));
            }
            await writeDataToStream(stream, chunk);
        }
        stream.end('', 'utf8');
    };

    const csvs = [{ name: 'csv1.csv' }, { name: 'csv2.csv' }];
    for (const csv of csvs) {
        await writeToZipStream(csv);
    }
    zip.end();
    console.log('finished');
}
```

I could download the zip file at the client side but instead of two files I only have one file (file name is the same as the name of the zip file, here *myFile*) with the all data inside:

```
id,field1,field2
0,test1,test2
1,test1,test2
2,test1,test2
3,test1,test2
...
197,test1,test2
198,test1,test2
199,test1,test2
id,field1,field2
0,test1,test2
1,test1,test2
2,test1,test2
3,test1,test2
...
```

Please consider:

- Because of size of data, I don't want to create csv files at the server or keep all data in memory, instead I want to stream data directly to the client but via zipped csv files.
- Data are fetched asynchronously from database, hence they are not totally available at once.

Considering this, I have two questions to fix the issues:

1. how to create files correctly in the zip stream (and the zip downloaded) using transform streams?
2. how to properly name files in the zip stream (and the zip downloaded)?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: zip != gzip. Gzip is a compression algorythim, it just compresses data. If you need files inside, then you need to create a tarball with files, which you then compress.

Comment: @Marc, would you introduce some resources on this, how do I manage tarball and compression using streams?

Comment: I finally implemented this requirement by creating the files locally (at the server) and then streaming a zip file out of the parent directory of the file to the client.